# Angular How to execute a function when a property changes in a component

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi i am new to angular

this is my angular component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  user = ""
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Is there a way that I can execute a block of code whenever this user variable changes?

Comment: Many ways to do that, but need to know your logic. What are you aiming for ? What is your end target ?

Comment: [Ask about your real goal instead of some intermediate solution you propose.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can set condition on user or if the user is change from html then you can call that method on (change)="methodName()"

Comment: what if the user variable data is coming from a service? there i cant right html right?